# Meteor .depends() method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working through the Discover Meteor book and I'm stuck on the example from page 137

```
var _currentLikeCount = 0;
var _currentLikeCountListeners = new Deps.Dependency();


currentLikeCount = function() {
_currentLikeCountListeners.depend();
return currentLikeCount;
}

Meteor.setInterval(function() {
 var postId;
  if (Meteor.user() && postId = Session.get('currentPostId')) {
   getFacebookLikeCount(Meteor.user(), Posts.find(postId),
    function(err, count) {
  if (!err && count !== _currentLikeCount) {
   _currentLikeCount = count;
   _currentLikeCountListeners.changed();
 }
});
}
}, 5 * 1000);
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what "Deps.Dependency()" and "depend()" are doing in this code. What type of functionality is exhibited in this code? It's more or less glossed over in the book and I'm having a hard time finding an explanation that makes send in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things in Meteor are reactive - that means when a value changes in the data, all things that depend on that value recalculate themselves.

To make this possible such thing has to know which value it depends on. This is tracked by setting Dependencies. So in other words, Dependencies are the low-level mechanism you need to use if you want to make things recalculate themselves automatically.

There are three important lines in the code you've posted:

```
var _currentLikeCountListeners = new Deps.Dependency();
```

This creates a new dependency object that will be used to track `_currentLikeCount` changes.

```
_currentLikeCountListeners.depend();
```

This method, used in a reactive function, makes that function listen to the dependency. So whenever the dependency changes, function will be recalculated. Note here that not all functions are reactive ones - it needs to be so called "reactive computation". Don't worry about it on the beginning, just note that template helpers are ok.

```
_currentLikeCountListeners.changed();
```

This is the actual line that triggers this recalculation.